# Oracle XMLCONCAT() function - missing tag name on Oracle version 19c

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle19c

When I run first SQL query on Oracle 19c, <strange_elem> is missing.
Why ? Is it Oracle bug ?

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jul 22 10:46:19 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Jul 22 2020 10:31:51 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

sql> -- missing <strange_elem> !!!
sql> SELECT
  2     Xmlforest(
  3          xmlconcat(xmlelement("data", 'abc')) as "strange_elem"
  4          ,dbms_utility.get_time  "next"
  5      )||' ' result
  6      FROM dual;
RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<data>abc</data><next>1036336429</next>
```

```
sql> -- <strange_elem> is present when <next> elem is ommited
sql> SELECT
  2     Xmlforest(
  3          xmlconcat(xmlelement("data", 'abc')) as "strange_elem"
  4      )||' ' result
  5      FROM dual;
RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<strange_elem><data>abc</data></strange_elem>
```

```
sql> -- <strange_elem> is present when <next> elem value is not function, but hard coded value !
sql> SELECT
  2     Xmlforest(
  3          xmlconcat(xmlelement("data", 'abc')) as "strange_elem"
  4          ,'1' "next"
  5      )||' ' result
  6      FROM dual;
RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<strange_elem><data>abc</data></strange_elem><next>1</next>
```

On Oracle 12c I get in all 3 SQL queries same result. <strange_elem> is present in result.

Comment: I got "strange_elem" both in 12.2 and in 19c

Comment: agree with @RobertoHernandez, all three give me strange_elem in 19c.

Answer (score 1):

check this Doc ID 2716320.1 and apply patch

Comment: Please add a link and explanation if possible as to why this was happening.